# iOS in app purchase for arabic language in objective c

Tags: objective-c, ios8, in-app-purchase

Currently I am working on an arabic project in which I have implemented in app purchases successfully in english language but my requirements are to show the in app products in arabic language. I have read the apple guideline which say arabic is not supported for in app purchase.
Any body help me how can I do this?
Also I want to show in app alerts in arabic too.

Comment: For in-app purchase, apple care for ID (product id) which we pass for the purchase.. regarding the arabic text, you can put any language text for the product which will be shown...

Comment: Also can you tell me more details for "I have read the apple guideline which say arabic is not supported for in app purchase." where exactly arabic text will be displayed? I have multiple arabic apps where I have in-app purchase...

Comment: Arabic language is included in languages list, it simply means it is not supported by apple.isn't it?

Comment: what exactly you want to do in In-App with arabic? I also work in arab countries and have implemented in-app...

Comment: I want to show my in app alert in arabic text i.e when product buy alert appear buy should be show شراء and Cancel should be إلغاء.
Can you tell me how can I do this?

Comment: you can't do that... that is as per mobile device language...